# Correlation between selfadjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Denote by $H_1$ and $H_2$ some Hilbert spaces and $S: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ is some linear bounded operator, such that $SS^*: H_1\rightarrow H_1$ is some compact lineare operator, where $S^*$ denotes the adjoint operator.

My question is how do $SS^*$ and $S^*S$ correlate? Do both operators have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: In general, $S^*S$ and $SS^*$ have the same spectrum up to a possible eigenvalue of $0$. This is easily shown by acting on the left by $S$ or $S^*$ accordingly in the eigenvalue equations. Since these are compact, you can conclude a little more.

Comment: thank you verry much!

Comment: Not all compact operators are trace-class.